# Definition of addition by transfinite recursion.

Tags: set-theory, foundations, transfinite-recursion

Transfinite recursion theorem from T.Jech Set Theory:

> Let G be a function (on V), then (2.6) below defines a unique function
>   F on Ord such that $F (α) = G(F \restriction  α)$ for each α.
>
> (2.6) $$(F(α) = x) ↔ \mbox{there is a sequence} \langle a_ξ : ξ <
> > α\rangle \mbox{such that:}$$ $$(i)\quad(∀ξ < α) a_ξ = G(\langle a_η :
> > η < ξ\rangle);$$ $$(ii)\quad x = G(\langle a_ξ : ξ < α\rangle).$$

Question: I want to define addition on ordinals. Then I need to define G somehow firstly. How?
I calculated that $$G(\emptyset)=\alpha,$$ 
$$G(\{\langle 0, \alpha \rangle\})=\alpha+1,$$
$$G(\{\langle 0, \alpha \rangle, \langle 1, \alpha+1 \rangle\})=(\alpha+1)+1$$
$$...$$
How to define G? We need to use some formula with two free variables; then prove that it defines an operation on all sets; then introduce functional symbol G; then apply transfinite recursion theorem. Which formula should I use and start with?

How to obtain G from this:

> Definition 2.18 (Addition). For all ordinal numbers α $$(i) α + 0 =
> > α,$$ $$(ii) α + (β + 1) = (α + β) + 1, \mbox{for all β},$$ $$(iii) α + β =
> > \lim_{ξ→β} (α + ξ)\mbox{ for all limit β > 0}.$$

Comment: For every $\alpha$ define $\alpha+\beta$ recursively.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  I don't understand. Ok, we fixed alpha. So G=? . 1) Do you agree that we need G to be defined somehow before we define addition? 2) Could you please, provide a definition of G for our particular case? (it may be some formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that $\alpha+\beta=\gamma$ iff there is some function $F$ such that

- $F(0)=\alpha$;
- $F(\delta+1)=F(\delta)+1$; and
- $F(\delta)=\sup_{\xi<\delta}F(\xi)$ for $\delta$ a limit;

and $\beta\in \mathrm{dom}(F)$ and $F(\beta)=\gamma$.  Transfinite recursion is what allows you to get such an $F$.

But your question is what $G$ gives you this $F$?  Well, the natural one as we've been given: for a set $X$, we break down into cases.  In particular, take $G(X)$ to be $\alpha$ if $X=\emptyset$ or isn't a function with its domain an ordinal, and otherwise define

$$ G(X) = \begin{cases}
   \sup \mathrm{ran}(X)+1 & \text{if }\mathrm{dom}(X)\text{ is a successor ordinal}\\
\sup \mathrm{ran}(X)&\text{if }\mathrm{dom}(X)\text{ is a limit ordinal.}
\end{cases}$$

As is usual for things defined by recursion, $G$ is just some function that doesn't depend on $F$ or $F\restriction \alpha$.  We use the restrictions in defining $F$, not $G$.  $G$ just tells you how to step forward, and (for the most part) can just be broken down into cases like the above definition.

Comment: F(w)=G(F|'w)=(sup ran (F|'w))=w    , so 1+w=w , looks good. Thanks a lot. Could you provide similar function G but for multiplication? Or should I use the same one?

Comment: @ged You would use a *similar* function.  The idea behind most definitions by recursion is that ordinals can be broken down into three types: $0$, successors, and limits.  So if we specify what happens at each of these stages, we define the function.  So all we need to define $G$ is to break down into these kinds of cases, as was done above with addition.  See if you can come up with one for multiplication yourself.  Note that you now have addition as a function you can use to define multiplication with.

Comment: You can combine the whole thing into $G(X)=\bigcup\{X(x)\cup\{X(x)\}\mid x\in\operatorname{dom}(X)\}$.

Comment: AsafKaragila, i think that it also equivalent to G(X)=⋃(succ[ran(X)]), a little bit shorter, where [] means image.

Comment: @AsafKaragila , we have same errors in the comments above. Post was edited and now G(0) should be equal to alpha. We can still combine, but only the "otherwise" part of it

Comment: @ged: The question of how much longer/shorter is your notation depends on what notation you deem acceptable.