# How to define ordinal addition

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory, definition, ordinals, transfinite-recursion

From Jech's *Set Theory*:

> We shall now define addition, multiplication and exponentiation of ordinal numbers, using Transfinite Recursion.
>
> **Definition 2.18 (Addition).** For all ordinal numbers $\alpha$
>
> 1. $\alpha + 0 = \alpha$,
> 2. $\alpha + (\beta + 1) = (\alpha + \beta) + 1$, for all $\beta$,
> 3. $\alpha + \beta = \lim_{\xi\to\beta}(\alpha+\xi)$, for all limit ordinals $\beta$.

Though he omits the details, which I'm trying to bring to light. After reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3505257/362026), it seems to me (please correct me if I'm wrong) that the sketch (some details are missing, hence the '$?$' signs) of the definition is as follows:

**Definition (Addition).** Fix $\alpha$. Define a function $G$ on $U=\{x:x=x\}$ such that, for any $\beta$-sequence $\{a_\xi:\xi<\beta\}$ we get
$$
G : \{a_\xi\}\mapsto 
\begin{cases}
\alpha & \text{ if $\beta=0$}\\ 
? & \text{ if $\text{Suc}(\beta)$}\\
? & \text{ if $\text{Lim}(\beta)$}
\end{cases}
$$
and, by transfinite recursion, there is a function
$$F:\text{ON}\to U : \beta \mapsto G(F\upharpoonright \beta) = G(F_\xi : \xi<\beta) = 
\begin{cases}
\alpha & \text{ if $\beta=0$}\\
F(\beta-1)+1 & \text{ if $\text{Suc}(\beta)$}\\
\lim_{\xi\to\beta}F(\xi) & \text{ if $\text{Lim}(\beta)$}
\end{cases}
$$

---

What is the meaning of $\sup\text{ran}(X)$ in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3505257/362026)? I do not recall seeing this terminology in the book. As $X$ is a transfinite (function) sequence $(a_\xi:\xi<\beta)$ it's range ($\text{ran}$?) is the collection of the $a_\xi$. I'm uncertain what the supremum ($\sup$?) of this class is though. If it is $a_\beta$, then
$$
G : \{a_\xi\}\mapsto 
\begin{cases}
\alpha & \text{ if $\beta=0$}\\ 
a_\beta+1 & \text{ if $\text{Suc}(\beta)$}\\
a_\beta & \text{ if $\text{Lim}(\beta)$}
\end{cases}
$$
but I do not know how the existence of $F$ follows from this $G$ by transfinite recursion. Furthermore, can we even add $1$ to $a_\beta$?

---

What exactly is $G$, and how does the existence of $F$ follow from that of $G$ by transfinite recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comprehension is quite close. In your linked post, $\sup$ and $\operatorname{ran}$ indeed refer to supremum of a set and range of function respectively. The formal definition of supremum of a set of ordinals is just the union of them. The range of a set can be acquired by the replacement scheme.

So how do we add $1$ to $a_\beta$? In fact, $\gamma=\alpha+1$ is exactly another way to say $\gamma$ is the ordinal successor of $\alpha$, namely $\gamma=\operatorname{Succ}(\alpha):=\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$. Thus you don't have to define general addition of ordinals in advance.

I would prefer to write $G(\langle a_\xi\rangle_{\xi<\beta})=\sup_{\xi<\beta}(a_\xi+1) = \bigcup(\operatorname{Succ}"\langle a_\xi\rangle_{\xi<\beta})$ since this covers both successor and limit cases, but in the following I will stick to the original definition in that post.

---

For the following $G$,
$$
G(\varnothing) = \alpha \\
G(x)=\alpha \text{ if } x\text{ is not a function of ordinals} \\
G(\langle a_\xi\rangle_{\xi<\beta}) = a_{\beta_0}+1 \text{ if } \beta=\beta_0+1 \\
G(\langle a_\xi\rangle_{\xi<\beta}) = \cup_{\xi<\beta} a_\xi \text{ if } \beta \text{ is a limit ordinal}
$$
the corresponding $F$ defined by Theorem 2.15 satisfies $F(\beta)=G(F\restriction\beta)$ for all ordinals $\beta$. From definition of $G$ we can tell that
$$
F(\beta) = G(\langle F(\xi)\rangle_{\xi<\beta}) 
= \begin{cases}
\alpha & \text{ if $\beta=0$}\\ 
F(\beta_0)+1 & \text{ if $\beta=\beta_0+1$}\\
\sup_{\xi<\beta} F(\beta_\xi) & \text{ if $\beta=\lim_{\xi<\beta}$}
\end{cases}
$$
as required.

Comment: What is the meaning of $a_{\beta_0}$? I'm guessing you meant $\alpha_{\beta_0}$, and even then, shouldn't $\alpha_\gamma$ be defined only for $\gamma < \beta$?

Comment: @Sam I meant exactly $a_{\beta_0}$, the $\beta_0$-th element in the sequence $\langle a_\xi\rangle_{\xi<\beta}$. Since $\beta_0+1=\beta$, $\beta_0<\beta$, and thus $a_{\beta_0}$ (i.e. the last element in the sequence) is defined.