# How is transifnite recursion applied?

Tags: set-theory, definition, cardinals, ordinals, transfinite-recursion

I've been struggling to understand how ordinal addition, multiplication, and exponentiation, along with the Aleph function $\aleph$, are defined using Transfinite Recursion in Jech's *Set Theory* or Holz's, Steffens' & Weitz' *Introduction to Cardinal Arithmetic*. The former, for example, simply writes

> We shall now define addition, multiplication and exponentiation of ordinal
> numbers, using Transfinite Recursion.

> **Definition 2.18 (Addition).** For all ordinal numbers $α$
>
> 1. $α +0= α$,
> 2. $α + (β + 1) = (α + β) + 1$, for all $β$,
> 3. $α + β = \lim_{ξ→β}(α + ξ)$ for all limit $β > 0$.

> **Definition 2.19 (Multiplication).** For all ordinal numbers $α$...

> **Definition 2.20 (Exponentiation).** For all ordinal numbers $α$...

before continuing as if the definition was fully clear to the reader (perhaps it usually is, but it has remained unclear to me). My understanding, after reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3505257/362026) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4855423/362026) post, is that there is an intermediate step (**Theorem(?)** below) that is used implicitly. I'm writing the current post to check whether my understanding is correct.

---

**Notation:**

- $V$ is the universal class $\{x:x=x\}$.
- $\text{Ord}$ is the class of Ordinals.
- $\text{Suc}$ is the class of successor ordinals.
- $\text{Lim}$ is the class of limit ordinals.
- If $\beta$ is the successor ordinal of $\alpha$, then $\beta = \alpha + 1$ and $\alpha = \beta - 1$.
- If $\kappa$ is a cardinal, then the smallest cardinal greater than $\kappa$ is written $\kappa^+$.

---

From Jech's *Set Theory*:

> **Theorem 2.15 (Transfinite Recursion).** Let $G$ be a function (on $V$ ),
> then there is a unique function $F$ on $\text{Ord}$ such that
> $$F(α) = G(F\upharpoonrightα)$$
> for each $α\in\text{Ord}$. In other words, if we let $a_α = F(α)$, then for each $\alpha$
> $$a_α = G\left(\langle a_ξ : ξ<α\rangle\right).$$

---

***First question:** is the following result true?*

**Theorem(?)** Suppose we are given

1. Any set $x_0$.
2. A function $s$ on $\text{Suc}$.

Then, there exists a function $F$ on $\text{Ord}$ such that

$$F:\alpha \mapsto 
\begin{cases}
x_0 & \text{ if } \alpha = 0\\
s\circ F(\alpha-1) & \text{ if } \alpha\in\text{Suc}\\
\lim_{\xi\to\alpha}F(\xi) & \text{ if } \alpha\in\text{Lim}\\
\end{cases}$$

*Proof:* let $G$ be a function on $V$ defined by

$$G:x \mapsto 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x\text{ is not a function of ordinals}\\
x_0 & \text{ if } x = 0\\
s(a_{\alpha-1}) & \text{ if } x = \langle a_\xi : \xi<\alpha\in\text{Suc}\rangle\\
\lim_{\xi\to\alpha}a_\xi & \text{ if } x = \langle a_\xi : \xi<\alpha\in\text{Lim}\rangle\\
\end{cases}$$

by Trasfinite Recursion, there is a function $F$ on $\text{Ord}$ such that $\alpha\mapsto G(F\upharpoonright \alpha)$. We show all three conditions are met:

- $0\mapsto 0$ trivially.
- If $\alpha\in\text{Suc}$, then $F(\alpha) = G(F \upharpoonright \alpha) = G(\langle F(\xi) : \xi < \alpha\in\text{Suc}\rangle) = s\circ F(\alpha-1)$, as wanted.
- If $\alpha\in\text{Lim}$, then $F(\alpha) = G(F \upharpoonright \alpha) = G(\langle F(\xi) : \xi < \alpha\in\text{Lim}\rangle) = \lim_{\xi\to\alpha}F(\xi)$, as wanted.
  $$\square$$

---

Assuming the first question was answered in the affirmative:

***Second question:** is the theorem above the implicit intermediate step between Transfinite Recursion and defining ordinal addition, multiplication, exponentiation, the Aleph function, etc?*

As an example, ordinal addition is often defined by applying, though it's not explain exactly how, Transfinite Recursion to the three conditions below:

1. $\alpha + 0 = \alpha$.
2. $\alpha + \beta = \left[\alpha + (\beta-1)\right] + 1$ if $\beta\in\text{Suc}$.
3. $\alpha + \beta = \lim_{\xi\to\beta}(\alpha + \beta)$ if $\beta\in\text{Lim}$.

As I see it **Theorem(?)** is being applied with $x_0 = 0$ and $s : \beta\mapsto \beta + 1$ to define ordinal addition. Ordinal multiplication (on the right, by $\alpha$) is defined by setting $x_0 = 0$ and $s:\beta\mapsto\beta+\alpha$, while ordinal exponentiation (base $\alpha$) sets $x_0 = 1$ and $s:\beta\mapsto\beta\cdot\alpha$.

As a last example, the Aleph function is defined using **Theorem(?)** with $x_0 = \omega$ and $s:\kappa\mapsto\kappa^+$ where $\kappa^+$ denotes the smallest cardinal greater than $\kappa$.

Comment: Your theorem is not quite right. There are a few problems: you say that $s$ is defined on successors, but you actually typically need it at all ordinals. You also need $s$ to be ordinal-valued, otherwise, there will be problems. Finally, you need some kind of assumption to ensure that the limit written in the statement even exists (for example, that $s$ is monotone).

Comment: I do see now why it needs to be ordinal-valued. Could you elaborate on the other two points?

Comment: Rather, consider the following example: let $s$ be the identity on successors (and not defined elsewhere). Then $F$ is not well-defined at $\omega+1$. And the following example: let $x_0=0$, $s(0)=1$, $s(1)=0$. Then $F(n)=n+1\mod 2$ for $n\in \omega$ and $\lim_{\xi\to \omega}F(\xi)$ is not well-defined.